# Keras CNN with regression - MSE decreasing very slowly

Tags: keras, regression

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras import backend as K

def sacc(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(K.round(y_true), K.round(y_pred)))

batch_size = 256
epochs = 10000
img_rows, img_cols, channels = 32, 32, 3 # input image dimensions

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], channels, img_rows, img_cols)
    X_val = X_val.reshape(X_val.shape[0], channels, img_rows, img_cols)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], channels, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (channels, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, channels)
    X_val = X_val.reshape(X_val.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, channels)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, channels)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, channels)

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), metrics=[sacc])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

score = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, verbose=0)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

I have this keras model which has regression as the final layer instead of softmax. I am trying to predict a score (0.0 to 100.0) for a given image. The issue I am seeing is it is taking >10000 epochs to train and MSE decreases very slowly. Is that expected or is there something wrong with my code? Any tips or comments appreciated.

Comment: you could try different optimizers, like `sgd`,`adam`, or `rmsprop`, those may converge faster than `Adadelta`

Comment: Also, you can explore the learning rate in them, such as `optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)` -- Higher learning rates do faster training, but may be too much and simply "miss the point", diverging from good results.

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try.

Comment: @Nira how did you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using ReLU as your activation function in output layer because it gives continuous output in range `0 to infinity`. You want your output to be between `0 to 100.0`.
For regression problem, you CAN create output layer without any activation function as you are interested in numerical values without any transformation i.e. to avoid using reverse_transform later on test data to get actual numerical values.

Regression problems are sensitive to outliers so check if there are any outliers. 
Other than this, try using `rmsprop` or `adam` for regression and do a grid search on different `learning rate`.